# Is it possible to set parent to JWindow after it was created?

Tags: java, swing, jwindow

Is it possible to set parent to `JWindow` after it was created? For example:

```
public class SomeJWindow extends JWindow {

  public SomeJWindow (JFrame parent) {
      //super(parent); - parent not set yet.
    }

}
```

and later set `parent` to `SomeJWindow`.

Comment: What does the javadoc for JWindow say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not it isn't possible, because

- Top-Level Container is based on peer from Native OS, parent isn't possible to change, set after Top-Level Container is initialized
- not possible to delegate, change parent from one Top-Level Container to another
- I can't found any access to modify xxx$SharedOwnerFrame

  ---
- Top-Level Container haven't implementer finalize() in API, then its life_cycle ended with current JVM